# Android call state listener stops working after some time

Tags: android

I am experiencing a bit of a strange defect that I am trying to resolve.

Here is the configuration:
 * A foreground service that has 2 listeners: 
 ** sms received listener
 ** call state listener

- I have left the app and it's service on, just for testing purposes.
- It handled both missed calls and text messages
- After some time (roughly 8 - 10 hours), it stopped receiving phone state events and thus did not handle missed calls any more.
- However, sms received listener continued working just fine.

This morning I verified that no phone state events are detected, meaning that receiver is not listening to events any more.

What could be the issue here? This is the first time I am experiencing it and I have been testing for a few days now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be purely Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 issue and only happened once. I have been testing on Galaxy S5 in parallel for few days and I see absolutely no issues.

Comment: So, I have logged what happens. Xiaomi issue only. Call receiver goes directly to IDLE state... re running app gets thing back to normal, so it gets RINGING, IDLE etc... I guess I will update the OS and see if it helps or not.

Comment: I'm testing in Huawei and Samsung devices. After installing the app. it was working very fine for a week, after that it was stopped. then I again need to open that app to run the service in the background. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159603/5359340  this is coding. want I change anything from that, please help me working perfectly.